# C++ return length of string including contained null terminator bytes

Tags: string, string-length

The methods for getting the length of a string in C++ all seem to count up to a null terminating byte, then they either include it in the length or not and then return the length up to then.  Well lets say I have a String like this:
'h','e','l','l','o','\0','t','h','e','r','e'
Now if you call length on this string you will get 5 as the length.  I need a call on this string that will return 11.  Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean string literals (`"abc"`) or `std::string`?

Comment: If you absolutely need the string to contain a null char, you should store it's size separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A C++ string is by definition also a C-string, so it will always be null terminated. For this particular problem, I recommend using std::vector< char >

Comment: As far as I can tell, casting a string to a vector requires you know the length of the string...

Comment: @TravisElliott If you can elaborate a little more and show some sample code from your particular problem I'll do my best to suggest a solution.

Comment: @Trey Yes, you're right, but the string may be coming from a file buffer or socket stream as an array. In this case there's a good chance that the buffer size is hardcoded or is set by some API. Putting this data on a vector can ease operations like concatenation and getting the stored length.